# How to create simple CRUD module in Magento 1?

Tags: magento-1.9, crud

I'm new to Magento 1. I want to create 1 simple CRUD Operation module.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend you to give this a try: https://github.com/tzyganu/UMC1.9
even if it's discontinued and hasn't been updated in 6+ years, Magento 1 wasn't updated either so there is a high chance it will still work.
You can install the module in your magento 1 instance and follow the [documentation](https://github.com/tzyganu/UMC1.9/wiki) to create your CRUD module.
It is more or less similar to creating a db table using PHPMyAdmin.